# PHP - MySQL "next" - "previous" link with ordering

Tags: php, mysql, navigation, pagination, fetch

I have a table like this

```
id    |   name      |  image     |    ordering
------+-------------+------------+--------------
1     |   name 1    |  one.jpg   |      5
------+-------------+------------+--------------
2     |   name 2    |  two.jpg   |      2
------+-------------+------------+--------------
3     |   name 3    |  thr.jpg   |      3
------+-------------+------------+--------------
4     |   name 4    |  for.jpg   |      7
------+-------------+------------+--------------
5     |   name 5    |  fiv.jpg   |      1
------+-------------+------------+--------------
6     |   name 6    |  six.jpg   |      9
------+-------------+------------+--------------
```

My requirement to show first image in a page according to the ordering. The following query works for me

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ordering ASC LIMIT 0,1 - row with id 5 will return
```

Next I have to show 2 links at the bottom "Prev" and "Next" ( Since this is the first page dont need to show "Prev" )

Okey .. By pressing on "Next" I have to show the next page ( ie according to the table its row with id 2 ). In that page need to show "prev" which will leads to first result. "Next" from that page must leads to row with id 3

I have tried

```
select * from images where id < $local_id order by id desc limit 1
 select * from images where id > $local_id order by id asc limit 1
```

But since it having the ordering it wont work...

Can any one please share an idea with me ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL `LIMIT X, Y` is the range you want to get, where X is the starting row (0 being the first row) and Y being the number of rows to return

To achieve what you want you would need to use page numbers for each page you were on, then use them to calculate the X value, Y would always be 1 as you only want 1 image on each page.

Something like this would get you started:

```
<?php

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$startPoint = $page - 1;

$query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ordering ASC LIMIT $startPoint,1";

$rowCount = 0; // replace this with a count of all your rows/images
```

Then you links would be like

```
<a href="index.php?page=1">First</a>
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page - 1?>">Prev</a>
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page + 1?>">Next</a>
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $rowCount;?>Last</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Next

```
select * from images where id = $local_id+1 limit 1
```

Previous

```
select * from images where id = $local_id-1 limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change in limit to achieve it, change the limit as per changing of page.

```
    SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ordering ASC LIMIT 1,1 - row with id 2 will return
    SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY ordering ASC LIMIT 2,1 - row with id 3 will return
```

Answer (score 1):

Not good +1 / -1 is bad, prevent id (page) is not exist, use sql where previous id.

Example ur main page id 3 and id 4 not exist... happen:

Next:

```
select * from images where id = (select min(id) from images where id > 4)
```

Previous:

```
select * from images where id = (select max(id) from images where id < 4)
```

Comment: This is a really slick and simple solution. I'm a novice, so unless I"m missing something, i love it.